# Different modes in different windows? (Blender)

Tags: interface

Is it possible to view Edit mode in one window and Object mode in another window as shown in image?
[image]

Comment: no i don't think you can do that

Comment: @Matthew That is exactly what I want. One view where object mode is visible with subsurf applied. Another view where edit mode is visible with subsurf not applied. I know this isn't possible in vanilla blender, but maybe an addon. And come on, I can't be the only one who needs such a feature.

Comment: Man that's such a useful feature! Not sure why you don't see the benefits? @Matthew

Answer (score 8):

Unfortunately no. But maybe you should describe your problem in more detail so that an alternative solution can be found.

For example, maybe you need to see vertices that are hidden when "subdivision surfaces" are applied. Then you need to enable the "on cage" option.
[image]

with this option you can modify the mesh and see the result immediately.
[image]

Comment: This isn't what I am asking. This does not serve the purpose.